# "An other" vs "another"

Tags: word-choice, orthography, determiners, spacing

I just edited [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30337/4671) on unix.sx. The original sentence was

> But it won't transform it to **an other** format.

I changed this to

> But it won't transform it to **another** format.

The second form is standard, but is the first correct?

Comment: There is the possibility that you should have corrected it to "any other" instead of "another"... :-)

Comment: @Hellion: What is the difference between these?

Comment: “Any other” and “another” are very similar in meaning, but not always interchangeable. “He loves another woman” means a particular woman. “He loves any other woman” means he is not so particular.

Comment: @MetaEd: Sure. My question was about which was more suitable in this context, and why.

Comment: When things are promoted or defended solely because of fashion or tradition, it means there is no real justification. Hence my skepticism every time there is mention of either word.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The string *an other* is vanishingly rare in English. In contrast *another* is positively pervasive. I think it would be fair to say that the second has eclipsed the first to the point of making the first unacceptable, even though it is a grammatical string.

Both *an* and *another* are members of the category of determiners, while *other*, on the other hand, is an adjective. There's no grammatical reason why *DET* + *ADJ* would be unacceptable. So, it must simply be a matter of convention that makes *an other* unacceptable...

Comment: "An other" is not preferred and, perhaps, even generally avoided because it is out of fashion, but is it really unacceptable if it is not incorrect?

Comment: There is a reason: *another* [**blocks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28linguistics%29) the ungrammatical combination *\*an other*.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a general rule of thumb: if you mean "a different [noun]", then it is more appropriate to use "an other"; if you mean "an additional [noun]", then it is more appropriate to use "another".

So in your example you should use "But it won't transform it to an other format."

Also take a look at Brett Reynolds' answer. It is good from a syntactical point of view.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this rule? I can find no dictionary support for it, or indeed for the existence of ‘an other’ in current English at all, whereas both meanings you mention are given for ‘another’ in all dictionaries I have checked.

Comment: No, I was just speaking for experience. That "rule of thumb" is just something I made up because there are cases when "another" doesn't fit with what you are actually trying to say.

Comment: I've thought about this more, and I don't think this answer is completely accurate. I think it is more common to use "another" in either case. However, "an other" does emphasize that you are talking about a different something, whereas "another" implies that you are talking about some other random thing.

Comment: https://oneminuteenglish.org/en/an-other-vs-another/ This source suggests the same usage as MageWind, and this one suggests the original use was the 'additional' use https://www.etymonline.com/word/another though I'd say "another" can be used in either case now.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, just because "an other" is "vanishingly rare", that doesn't make its usage "unacceptable".  In my situation, which is advising (via a letter) a candidate for an employment position who has not been chosen, it doesn't seem appropriate for me to tell him that "another" candidate has been selected, but it does seem appropriate for me to tell him that "an other" candidate has been selected.  My aversion to "another" is because that seems to me to be saying that an additional candidate has been selected, rather than a different candidate being selected.  Bottom line...that distinction is my "rule of thumb" too.

Comment: Both *an other* and *another* can have both the meanings that you suggest, and the candidate has no way of knowing that you personally differentiate between them in this way.

Comment: I think user67403 is pointing out how using one is a stylist way of emphasizing something.

Comment: When faced with this situation, I came to the same conclusion; namely, that another implies an additional, as in 'Mom, can I have another cookie?', whereas an other implies a different one.

Comment: Agreed but wouldn't telling her "a different" candidate was selected be more concise?

Answer (score 7):

Historically, *another* and *an other* are simply two ways to write the same thing, and those dictionaries that are extensive in their example quotations may include *an other* as an example of *another*.

A similar word is *cannot* which is merely a way to write *can not*.

There is no difference in meaning between the two; all meanings of all sense of one are also a meaning of a sense of the other.

But history having moved on, we simply don't use *an other* much as we don't use *mannes* for *man's*, *neyther* for *neither*, and so on. As such your edit was correct.

About the one case I can think of where *an other* is to be favoured over *another* is if translating Rimbaud's "Je est un autre", I'd favour "I is an other" to "I is another", but bending the rules to put an emphasis on the word *other* in this way is acceptable precisely because one has already broken them in using the rule-breaking "I is…" to match the rule-breaking "Je est…".

Comment: LOL  at the person who tried to "fix" the Rimbaud quote to "Je suis".

Comment: They seem to have gotten the translation wrong on [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Arthur_Rimbaud) as per your _feeling_.

Comment: @AlexisWilke well, not wrong as in there's no way to say definitively just how deliberately non-standard French should be translated. At least it keeps "I is…" rather than "I am…" which ends up as something quite different again.